# Odd phantom file found in the preferences directory of macOS

Tags: macos, bash, filesystems

Trying to troubleshoot a misbehaving app on macOS Mojave (10.14.4), I needed to see if its plist file existed. Here's what I found (`***` used to mask the name of the software which isn't relevant - I hope):

```
swamp: [Preferences] $ ls -l com.su*
ls: com.sur***.***.plist: No such file or directory
-rw-------  1 ccpalmer  staff    317 Jan 28 08:11 com.sublimetext.3.plist
-rw-------  1 ccpalmer  staff  21126 Mar 10  2018 com.sustworks.PhoneAmego.plist
swamp: [Preferences] $
```

Notice that I didn't ask for `com.sur***.***.plist` specifically, but bash returned it. Yet, that is precisely the file that the developer told me to delete.

Similarly, if I `su -l` and check, I see the same thing:

```
swamp: [Preferences] $ su -l
Password:
swamp:~ root# cd /Users/ccpalmer/Library/Preferences/
swamp:Preferences root# ls -l com.su*
ls: com.sur***.***.plist: No such file or directory
-rw-------  1 ccpalmer  staff    317 Jan 28 08:11 com.sublimetext.3.plist
-rw-------  1 ccpalmer  staff  21126 Mar 10  2018 com.sustworks.PhoneAmego.plist
swamp:Preferences root# logout
swamp: [Preferences] $
```

I ran DiskUtility First Aid and it completed successfully, but this problem didn't change.  Here's the result from that (which is the same as from running fsck):

```
Running First Aid on “ ” (disk1s1)

NOTE: First Aid will temporarily lock the startup volume.

Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking volume.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume   was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.77.8) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.260.7).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 16.
error: (oid 0x4c44d) apfs_root: btn: encrypted bit is different to the volume-wide one (0x0)
error: drec_key object (oid 0x3d6df0): invalid hash (0, expected 191f6d) of name (Intel HD Graphics 4000)
Snapshot is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.

Operation successful.
```

Any thoughts?

**Update (August 19, 2019)**: Spent a total of about 6 hours with Apple support up to "engineering" and have no answer. Surely someone here knows more than Apple does?

Comment: Is your `ls` command an alias, or just the plain command? What does `/bin/ls -l` (without specifying the name or a pattern) print when it gets to that file?

Comment: I believe that the most likely theory is that you have filesystem corruption.  Your ``/Users/ccpalmer/Library/Preferences`` directory contains an entry for ``com.surXXX.XXX.plist``, but it doesn’t point to a valid, accessible inode. Try running `fsck`.

Comment: Tried fsck, both as Diskutil and as root in single-user mode... no help. Same result.

Comment: ls command is NOT an alias.

Comment: fsck fails just like Disk Utility does.

Comment: What about starting up the system in single user mode or from another disk entirely and then seeing if you can remove that phantom file like that?

Comment: What happens when you do `ls | grep com.su`? You said you wanted to delete this file, so what happens if you do `rm 'com.sur***.***.plist'` (the single quotes are important)?

Comment: @JakeGould:  tried single user mode - no difference.

Comment: @dirkt: `ls | grep com.su` does not find the phantom file.  Your `rm` command fails to find the phantom file, and yet `rm com.sur***.***.plist` produces no error (as though it DID find the phantom file) but the file is still found by `ls` afterward, issuing the error message `ls: com.sur***.***.plist: No such file or directory`.

Comment: So this very much look like you have an entry in the directory, but this entry doesn't point to anything useful, and everytime any program tries to *use* this entry it runs into some kind of error. So in other words, file system corruption. I don't know enough about MacOS file system internals to suggest how to fix this. Just in case: You *have* done a cold boot?

Comment: Numerous cold boots, several SAFE mode fsck's, and more.

Comment: I believe Scott and dirkt are right that this is file system corruption. Has affected me too. Maybe you might find data/file recovery tools. Normally a *repair* tool like DiskWarrior would be best, but I don't know of any 3rd party *repair* tool updated for APFS yet because Apple hasn't released enough detailed info on APFS. See https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/590631/What+do+you+use+in+place+of+DiskWarrior+to+repair+data+for+APFS#answer591938

Comment: People suggest using fsck (which calls fsck_apfs), but your Details shows Apple's Disk Utility First Aid actually does try "Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1".  For me, it tried "Performing fsck_apfs -y -x /dev/rdisk1s1" but that did not fix the invalid fsroot tree. Stellar Data Recovery did not address my problem, but this article also discusses apfs, fsck, and fsck_apfs.  https://eclecticlight.co/2019/09/30/should-you-trust-disk-utilitys-first-aid-or-fsck/